# Why would one shot port forwarding fail, but two step port forwarding succeed?

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a situation where I am trying to reach `beta:3000`, which can only be accessed through server `alpha`.

If I do the following from my local computer:

```
ssh -fNL 3000:beta:3000 alpha
```

I get "connection refused" errors. However, if I do the following from my local computer:

```
ssh -fNL 3000:localhost:3000 alpha
```

along with this from `alpha`:

```
ssh -fNL 3000:localhost:3000 beta
```

then the connection goes through.  But I thought the two methods should have the same effect?  What could be causing the former approach to fail, while the latter succeeds?

Comment: is the port 3000 on `beta` accessible from `alpha` or it is bound just on localhost`?

Comment: Yes, port 3000 on `beta` is accessible from `alpha`.

Answer (score 0):

The former approach reaches non-loopback interface of `beta` while the latter reaches the loopback interface.

- The listening process on `beta` may not listen on the interface `alpha` connects to, yet do listen on the loopback interface;
- or the firewall on `beta` may interfere, but since it is uncommon to have a firewall on a loopback interface, the latter approach bypasses the firewall.